# Docker is building image with cached env variable

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

today I came across a weird bug. I am relatively new to Docker, today I was building a Docker environment for a Laravel application. I started with a docker-compose, this file contained the necessary environment variables. Then I deleted the docker-compose file to use only one Dockerfile, the problem occurs when building the app, I should copy the .env (which I know is bad practice, but now I'm just testing), but instead of using the values I have in .env uses the ones I had set in docker-compose. Now without this last file I still have the same problem. So far testie:

- Delete all containers, even offline ones
- Delete all images
- docker builder prune -a
- docker build --no-cache

Some clue ? I've been trying to solve this since this afternoon and it makes me sick >:| .

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV HOME /root
ENV LC_ALL          C.UTF-8
ENV LANG            en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE        en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php  && \
        apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get -y install php8.1 php-mysql php-curl php-mcrypt php-cli php-dev php-pear libsasl2-dev

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/ && \
    ln -s /usr/include/openssl/evp.h /usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/evp.h && \
    mkdir -p /usr/local/openssl/lib/ && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/local/openssl/lib/

RUN pecl install mongodb

RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini && \
    echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/mongodb.ini && \
    echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 8000

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get install wget php-zip unzip -y

RUN wget -O composer-setup.php https://getcomposer.org/installer

RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN composer install

RUN php artisan fix:passport

RUN php artisan migrate

RUN php artisan passport:install

CMD ["php", "artisan", "serve"]
```

Comment: you should not copy .env to your image. instead, just run the container pointing out to the env file. e.g: docker run -it --env-file=.env YOUR_IMAGE

Comment: I cant get the image to finish the build proccess, either create the container :(

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Laravel project to test your Dockerfile. I found a few issues in it:

1. mongodb extensions were present on laravel already do composer was raising an error due this conflict;
2. all the compose and laravel commands to restore packages and run the project were running under root which is not recommended so I created an user named ubuntu to do so;
3. every command in the Dockerfile will generate a docker "layer". As a good practice is recommended grouping those layers so they would make sense individually. E.g.: grouping all the required packages and installation steps (such as composer for instance) together in the same "RUN" command;

I have pushed the Dockerfile and a sample code to get composer running here: https://github.com/felipegouveiae/stackoverflow-73507087

I have left two branches: original, which I just made the necessary fixes to your Dockerfile and main, which I have enhanced that file as I would do on my projects.

This is the final Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as base

ENV HOME /root
ENV LC_ALL          C.UTF-8
ENV LANG            en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE        en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install software-properties-common -y && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php  && \
    apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get -y install php8.1 php-mysql php-curl php-mcrypt \
    php-cli php-dev php-pear libsasl2-dev wget php-zip unzip

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/ && \
    ln -s /usr/include/openssl/evp.h /usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/evp.h && \
    mkdir -p /usr/local/openssl/lib/ && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/local/openssl/lib/

RUN wget -O composer-setup.php https://getcomposer.org/installer && \
    php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

FROM base AS build

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu

RUN chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /usr/src/app 

USER ubuntu

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN composer install

RUN php artisan fix:passport &&\
    php artisan migrate && \
    php artisan passport:install

CMD ["php", "artisan", "serve"]

ENV PORT 8000

EXPOSE 8000
```

Please, test it with your project and let me know if that works.

Comment: GOAT. Hello ! How are you ? I finally managed to figure out the location of the problem, actually it is that the driver configuration in Laravel used an option where no matter what database is indicated in the .env file, it will authenticate against a database called "soowe". My partner forgot to mention this hahaha, it was an afternoon burning my head. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer, they are improvements to consider and that I will certainly add to the file, I am still starting with Docker and these help are the best! Greetings and have a good week :)